# rails 4 active admin multiple forms for one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, activeadmin, formtastic

Is there (an easy) way to create multiple forms for one model in activeadmin?

like [proxy models in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223375/multiple-modeladmins-views-for-same-model-in-django-admin)

Comment: Did you try this? Same way as creating an Index page. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546502/two-pages-for-the-same-resource-activeadmin/16559759#16559759

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to include `ActiveModel::Model`In your `model`as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715134/rails-4-having-a-proxy-model-to-combine-multiple-models).

Comment: where do i write these _models_? in app/models?

Comment: Yes! That is correct! In fact, you can include ActiveModel::Model in your any Ruby class

Comment: it seems that it might work, but i am kinda stuck in adding custom action views in actionadmin. anyway thank you for your answer, i looked at that question (which is in the link yu gave me) before, didn't think it might work for me back then.